# DRY Entity Framework Search Call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have an Entity Framework (v5.0) `DbContext` called `Entities` that is auto-generated by the framework (I think my design pattern is Database First).

I have this search command (shown in the snippet below) that I am calling throughout the application. I want to DRY up my controller code and re-factor this into a method call.

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
    var activeEvents = db.Events.Where(
        b => !b.removed &&
        b.start_date <= now &&
        b.end_date >= now
    );
}
```

Example after re-factoring.

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var activeEvents = db.Events.GetActive();
    // Or maybe it looks like db.GetActiveEvents();
    // I assume this is dictated by best practice
}
```

How would one go about achieving this? What is considered best practice?

Comment: I would probably make this in to an `IEventsService`, push it in through the ctor using DI and just simply call `var activeEvents = this.eventsService.GetActive();` ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie I am new to the C# programming language. What you said looks like a foreign language to me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You have the data context, then you have a service that sits on top of that and manages call to and from the database, then your MVC actions use that service to make calls. The DO container just makes it easier to add a reference to that service, but you can just as easily, in the controller ctor, add `this.eventService = new EventService(new Entities());`

Comment: Something like: https://gist.github.com/bchristie/6089367

Comment: Did you end up wiring it up using the service model?

Comment: Yes I did. It seems like a bunch of overhead. But it also seems like the best approach to separate the 'custom' code from the auto-generated stuff.

Comment: It can seem like overhead at first, but as your project grows and you begin reusing services (or sharing them between other services) you'll find it lends itself to expansion. You can also create unitsofwork which consume multiple services under the covers but make for a simple service call at the UI (e.g. UsersService & EventsService may be used in AuthService which creates the user and adds a login event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably take the service approach; You build your site with three main components:

- Presentation Layer
  This is the MVC website (but could be a mobile site, and application, whatever)
- Service Layer
  this handles the calls between the Presenation layer and the Data layer, applying business logic or whatever other checksums may be necessary (and keeping it away from the presentation layer)
- Data Layer
  Here your `Entities` reside and the context to the database.

For the sake of simplicity, you can keep this in one project, but if this becomes a big application you probably want to refactor it out in to separated libraries.

Now, as far as how to refactor your situation *now*, we add the service layer in there. I like to use interfaces so it makes things easy to test later on I can implement a "dummy" `IWhateverService` when I go to unit test, but keep the current implementation when running the actual application. Then you implement the interface to interface with the data and return what you need (or perform whatever actions are necessary [CRUD]). e.g.

```
public interface IEventService
{
    IEnumerable<Event> GetActive();
}

public class EventService : IEventService
{
    private readonly Entities entities;
    public EventService(Entities entities)
    {
        this.entities = entities;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Event> GetActive()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
        return this.entities.Events
            .Where(x => !x.removed)
            .Where(x => x.start_date <= now && x.end_date >= now)
            .AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Now that we have our service, we can plumb it through to the controller:

```
public class EventsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEventService eventService;

    public EventsService()
    {
        this.eventsService = new EventsService(new Entities());
    }

    // action that gets and views the active events
    public ActionResult Active()
    {
        var activeEvents = this.eventsService.Getactive();
        return View(activeEvents);
    }
}
```

As the project evolves, you can update your `IEventService` with CRUD operations (like I mentioned earlier):

```
public interface IEventService
{
    IEnumerable<Event> All { get; }

    void AddOrUpdateEvent(Event event);
    IEnumerable<Event> GetActive();
    void RemoveEvent(Event event);
}
```

Of course plumbing it through to `EventService`, then finally having that access within the `EventsController`.

To take it [several] steps further, you can look at Dependency Injection where you specify (one time) how to build an `IEventsService` then, when you need it, pass it as an argument to your controller's constructor (like so):

```
public OtherController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserService;
    private IEventService eventService;

    public OtherController(IUserService userService, IEventService eventService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.eventService = eventService;
    }

    /* actions */
}
```

Then, you can use something like Castle Windsor, ninject, or any of the other solutions that would involve a single map to these interfaces and then (magically) provide them to your controller's constructor for use. To give an example, here's a Castlewindsor configuration:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IEventService>().ImplementedBy<EventService>()
        .LifestyleSingleton()
);
```

Which essentially says that every time I need `IEventService` supply `EventService`.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use a partial class to achieve this.

Interface:

```
interface IMethods<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> ActiveItems();
}
```

Partial Class:

```
partial class Event :IMethods<Event>
{
    public IEnumerable<Event> ActiveItems()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new Entities())
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
                return db.Events.Where(b => !b.removed && b.start_date <= now && b.end_date >= now);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Test Method:

```
 public class TestClass
{
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var ativevnts = new Event().ActiveItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know why the keep rejecting the edit to your code. But without adding .ToEnumerable() on the `Where` call this method does not work.