# Entity Framework Rails like Scoping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, activerecord

How would you apply a global `Where` parameter to all Entity Framework search parameters.

For example, I have an entity (`Event`) that has a parameter called `Active` that is a boolean flag that determines if the record in question should be shown in the application.

How could you apply a "global" flag so that when searching for Events the framework automatically filters those Events that are not active?

In Rails ActiveRecord I would achieve this with [scoping](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes); what is the name for this in Entity Framework?

Snippet:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var activeEvents = db.Events.Where(b => b.Active)
}
```

Gets to be re-factored to:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var activeEvents = db.Events
}
```

Comment: What is your opinion of just having something like `EventDataSource.GetActiveEvents()` in your data access layer and just making that method your initial snippet? Overriding LINQ queries will be *very* confusing to future developers who assume both active and inactive will be included in `db.Events`.

Comment: @Ryan: Did you ask the same question twice? Where is my answer Just wondering!!!

Comment: @KosalaW No I did not ask the same question twice. I have another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882737/dry-entity-framework-search-call), which you answered, about re-factoring a method call. This one is about default search parameters. They just have similar examples.

Comment: Oh yea. They are similar. In EF there is no "particular" method to achieve this. it depends on the way you want to achieve it. I think Brad M's suggestion is also similar to what I said in my example.